# In Angular 10: can I refresh data from Resolver of parent route?

Tags: angular, state, refresh, reload, resolver

I have a parent route which uses a Resolver to get data.
I have several children of this route.
The child Components subscribe to this data in their ngOnInit() methods.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.data
        .subscribe((data: { collection: DataCollection }) => {
            this.collection = data.collection;
        });
}
```

The Resolver only runs on the first access of one of the child routes.

This has worked fine because until now changes to the state of `collection` have not had an impact on the UI, but this is no longer true. (In particular, buttons in the UI on various screens need to get enabled/disabled based on the state of `collection`.)

So the problem is that since the child routes/components have `collection` set from the Resolver which only fires once, they do not see updates to it, and cannot update their UIs accordingly.

I've seen a number of posts asking about a similar problem to this, but not one involving a Resolver.

Is there a way to force a re-run of the Resolver without navigating away from and then back to a route? Or is the solution to abandon the Resolver approach, use a service to the get data, and handle updates to it state with RXJS or something?

Thank you

Comment: I've been looking all over the internet and you are the only person I could find that is having the same issue. onSameUrlNavigation doesn't seem to re-trigger them since they're a parent. And I've tried a custom callback for runGuardsAndResolvers: `(from: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, to: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => boolean`. And I've also tried messing around with a custom RouteReuseStrategy. Can't get anything to manually re-trigger a parent resolver.

Answer (score -1):

did you try adding your Components as @ViewChild and implement something like a refresh function inside Components?

```
@ViewChild(Component1) comp1: Component1;
@ViewChild(Component2) comp2: Component2;
```

or

```
@ViewChildren(Component1) comps: QueryList<Component1>;

comp1.refresh();

refresh(state): void {
// this.data = state;
// this.data = initData();
}
```